# Is there a fully functional paradigm language that transpiles to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, transpiler

Is there a language which transpiles to JavaScript (like TypeScript, CoffeScript etc.) and is almost purely functional (like Haskell, Erlang, F#)?

I know there are libraries which helps maintain immutability (Underscore), and there are a lot of cool array functions and lambdas in ES6. But what I'm looking for is a functional like syntax and transpiler for it, so I can write functional JavaScript with not much effort.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/The_JavaScript_Problem is a pretty exhaustive list.

Comment: Haskell itself transpiles to JS! Check out https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/), [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/) or [PureScript](http://www.purescript.org/).

Other languages include [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript) (Clojure) and [Funscript](http://funscript.info/) (F#)

Of those, I've only really used Scala.js and Elm, both of which work extremely well in my opinion.

### Currying

In Elm and PureScript functions are curried by default.
In Scala Currying can be done very easily by using multiple parameter lists:

```
def curried(param1: Int)(param2: Int): Int = ...
```

Comment: Can you pipe and curry functions with them easily?

Comment: Elm looks great! Is there a way to achieve Haskell like pattern matching? Can I decompose lists to head and tail with a syntactic sugar?

Comment: Yup! :) Check out this cheat sheet: https://gist.github.com/yang-wei/4f563fbf81ff843e8b1e

Comment: Although, if you want something very close to Haskell, Purescript might be the better choice, but I haven't really tried it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you like F# you might like OCaml via [js_of_ocaml](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/) (better OCaml compatibility) or [BuckleScript](https://bucklescript.github.io/) (better JS interop) or even [Reason ML](https://reasonml.github.io/) (more modern syntax, including [JSX](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/jsx)).

If you like Haskell better, you could use [GHCJS](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs) (it's Haskell, targeting JS), [Purescript](http://www.purescript.org/) (strict evaluation means simpler JS), or [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/) (who needs type classes anyway).

I'm less sure about Erlang. There seem to have been some attempts (possibly somewhat successful) at targeting JS, but I'm not at all familiar with any of them.

Comment: Erlang can also be transpiled to JavaScript using [Erlscripten](https://github.com/erlscripten/erlscripten), which targets PureScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to stay at the .NET platform, and would want to use F# as your language to transpile to JavaScript, then I recommend looking at the following:

1.) [Fable](http://fable.io) - Fable brings together the power of the F# compiler and Babel to make JavaScript a true backend for F#. It works directly on F# source code, no compilation needed.

2.) [WebSharper](http://websharper.com) - A fundamentally different web framework
for developing functional and reactive .NET applications

Comment: I have tried websharper but I didn't really like it I will check Fable